# Jenkins Perforce Plugin - Sync multiple non continuous changelist numbers

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-plugins

I want to pull changes for non-continuous changelist numbers from perforce using the Perforce plugin on Jenkins. If I include the values as a comma separated list e.g. CH1, CH5, CH7 in the P4Label field of the perforce plugin, all changes in between CH1 and CH5 and CH5 and CH7 are synced. How would I be able to exclude the changes in between? I also tried CH1, @CH5, @CH7 but I got "Unintelligible revision specification" error.

Comment: Try: 'p4 sync //...@=CH1 //...@=CH5 //...@=CH7'. The special @= syntax specifies exactly the files submitted in that one changelist.

Comment: Bryan - I tried it from the command line and your suggestion works. However, when I add it to the P4Label field in Jenkins build configuration, it adds double quotes for the changelists and hence the command fails with the error:
com.tek42.perforce.PerforceException: Errors encountered while syncing: error: Unintelligible revision specification
Command:
p4 -s sync "//jenkins-ics-dev-exp/...@=37837 //jenkins-ics-dev-exp/...@=37946 //jenkins-ics-dev-exp/...@=37951 //jenkins-ics-dev-exp/...@=37955"